# image compression using python when image upload

Tags: python

when I will use image upload using chunk how I will compress my image before upload

how I will do this in python and not reduce quality of image

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: when you say `compress` do you means `zip` or convert to `jpg` ? And where and how do you upload it? You can read file, compress it to other file and later upload it. Some functions can work with `io.BytesIO` so you don't have to save it directly in file on disk but in file-like object in memory.